# PHP script makes a duplicate

Tags: php, linux, centos, wget

I have a long-running PHP script with `set_time_limit(0)` set. It works very good for `15 minutes (900 sec)` but then become something very strange: a second process with the same parameters starting! I see it because I am starting a new log file at the beginning of the script and there is two log files processing same data!

BTW script runs in background from PHP with

```
exec('wget http://example.com/script.php?id=NNN > /dev/null &');
```

This instruction normally runs only once, and I can not get what runs it second time after `900 seconds` (exact time).

Comment: Is your PHP running in safe-mode? As you cannot affect the max execution time while in safe mode.

Also what is your session lifetime? Maybe the session is timing out.

Comment: @i-CONICA PHP5.4 there is no safe-mode. And set_time_limit(0) works well, because first script instance not stopped, they running both till the end. PHP sessions not used here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because wget has a read time limit of 900sec. After it is reached, the download restarts.
You can set the timeout higher with the --timeout=seconds or the --read-timeout=seconds argument.
Or, you can start it directly from the shell(this way is much better).
Here is a link: [wget download options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html)
Here is the shell code(for Linux):

```
exec('php yourscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was definitely in wget, but I kick it out and remake whole script under commandline usage. Now it works great! Thanks a lot, pro.